# What is Doze mode timing?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-doze

As per [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#understand_doze)

> If a user leaves a device unplugged and stationary for a period of time, with the screen off, the device enters Doze mode.

How long does the device need to stay idle and stationary before Doze mode starts?

And so on:

> Periodically, the system exits Doze for a brief time to let apps complete their deferred activities. During thismaintenance window [...] Over time, the system schedules maintenance windows less and less frequently...

So, what is the maintenance windows interval and its increase rate?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the reference about Doze window frequency from [Base Lab Blog](https://lab.getbase.com/androids-new-doze-and-app-standby/)

> Maintenance windows in Doze won’t happen frequently. First window
>   occurs an hour after last activity, the next after two, the next after
>   four and so on.

There are beta apps that can customize the behavior to enter Doze mode (i.e. Greenify)